# Is it possible to originate a contract with an initial balance?

Tags: origination

Instead of doing two operations: 
1 - originate a contract 
2 - transfer tez to the contract,

is it possible to do both in a single operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the origination operation allows you to provide the contract balance.

In smartpy [origination page](https://smartpy.io/origination):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For sure! For instance, when originating with `tezos-client`, in this example I send 99 tez from the `bootstrap1` account when originating the contract `my_contract`:

```
$ tezos-client originate contract my_contract transferring 99 \ 
               from bootstrap1 running my_contract.tz \
               --init Unit --burn-cap 10.0
```